# why inverse is not there for one to one relationship in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

In hibernate, the inverse attribute will talk about the relationship owner.Then, why it is not there between one to one mapping association ?, why it existing only between list,set and so on ?. Please make me understand in this.

Comment: Inverse is present for bi-directional one-to-one if you use join tables. For reference http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join-121

Answer (score 0):

Let's see, when you use an @OneToOne, or @ManyToOne you are saying that your entity can receive one or multiples objects from another entity.

Hibernate will then understand that you just want an identifier of the object for the relationship. In other words, it will work like in SQL Relationships, you can create a column with the name "RelationedTable_ID" as an FK to state the bond between the two tables.

So, we can assume that Hibernate will also work like this. If you use an annotation that just reference one unique object from another entity then you do not need to use the inverse attribute, or any other forms of mapping.

However, while using an @OneToMany or @ManyToMany annotations you are stating that your entity WILL receive more than one object from another entity (a list, or a set, for example) and this will imply in a creation of a auxiliary table that will work as an mapping between the relationship.

In other words, while using single object relationship between your classes you will just need an attribute referencing the entity that you will need to reference. And while using multiple objects relationship you gonna need a list of objects that will require an extra table to map the relationship.

---

It's important too state too: You can avoid the creation of an additional table in your relationship by setting the annotation @JoinColumn("entityTarget_ID") just above your @OneToMany annotation that will go ahead of a list. Example:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn("entityTarget_ID")
private EntityTarget entityTarget;
```

Using the example above you will be able to reference two entities without the needing of an auxiliary table between them.

Comment: Got some idea,but need more clarification in this.